# Is there a way to embed a fully-functional (NOT read-only) Google Calendar into a website?

Tags: google-calendar, embed

I'm building a website to help a friend who schedules piano lessons. They use Google Calendar to track lessons, and I'm building a website for them to manage students, lesson packages, etc.

The customer-facing portion of the site can use a read-only embedded Google Calendar (which I already know how to find). **I would like to embed the fully-functional Google Calendar to their admin pages, however, so they can manage their schedule through the same web interface**, as could other people on their team who are logged in to the admin portion of their website.

Is there any way to do this without re-building Google Calendar from scratch using the APIs? (I keep considering doing that, with just the core "credit/edit/delete events" functionality, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel for no reason.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin FullCalendar:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/

And an AngularJS directive for it, if you are using angular:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar